# How to delete from specific line until specific line in a file on python

Tags: python, file

I have a file like this:

```
a
D
c
a
T
c
a
R
c
```

I want to delete from specific line (in this case 3) until another specific line (in this case 5), so the file would look like:

```
a
D
c
a
R
c
```

Comment: What kind of file are you reading in? What do you want to do with the file after you read it in and remove these lines? More information is needed to better answer the question.

Comment: is a vcf file, i want to delete a specific contact, i've already did to separate any contact in a function, now i need to delete it if is repeated

Comment: You need to do the delete in place or in a seperate file ?

Comment: delete from the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```py
def delete_line_range(filename, start_line, end_line):
    # read all lines
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        # iterate trough lines
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            # check if line is out of range
            if i < start_line or i > end_line:
                f.write(lines[i])
    f.close()
    return
```

Or if you want to delete multiple ranges

```py
def delete_line_ranges(filename, line_ranges):
    # read all lines
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        # iterate trough lines
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            # check if line is in range
            in_range = False
            for line_range in line_ranges:
                if i >= line_range[0] and i <= line_range[1]:
                    in_range = True
                    break
            # if not in range, write line
            if not in_range:
                f.write(lines[i])
    f.close()
    return
```

Where `line_ranges` is a list of tuples containing start and end line numbers.

Be aware that in both of these functions the line numbers start at 0.
Means if you want to delete line 3 to 5 like in your example you need to subtract 1 from both start and end line number.

```py
delete_line_range('test.txt', 2, 4) # deletes line 3 to 5 if you start counting from 1
```

## Edit

### Deleting Contacts out of vcf file.

---

Get range of specific contact:

```py
def get_contact_range(filename, name):
    # read all lines
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        # check if line is start of contact
        if lines[i].startswith('BEGIN:VCARD'):
            start_line = i
            continue
        if name in lines[i]:
            for j in range(i, len(lines)):
                # check if line is end of contact
                if lines[j].startswith('END:VCARD'):
                    end_line = j
                    return (start_line, end_line)
    return None
print(get_contact_range('test.vcf', 'John Doe'))
```

test.vcf

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//macOS 11.5.2//EN
N:Doe;John;;;
FN:John Doe
ORG:Sharpened Productions;
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=HOME;type=pref:johndoe@email.com
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK:johndoe@workemail.com
TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:123-456-7890
ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;12345 First Avenue;Hometown;NY;12345;United States
ADR;type=WORK:;;67890 Second Avenue;Businesstown;NY;67890;United States
NOTE:The man I met at the company networking event. He mentioned that he had some potential leads.
item1.URL;type=pref:https://fileinfo.com/
item1.X-ABLabel:_$!!$_
BDAY:2000-01-01
END:VCARD
```

Output:

```py
(0, 15)
```

Combine the above functions:

```py
def delete_contact(filename, name):
    # get start and end line of contact
    contact_range = get_contact_range(filename, name)
    # delete contact
    delete_line_range(filename, contact_range[0], contact_range[1])
    return
```

Multiple Contacts at once:

```
def delete_contacts(filename, names):
    # get start and end line of contacts
    line_ranges = []
    for name in names:
        contact_range = get_contact_range(filename, name)
        line_ranges.append((contact_range[0], contact_range[1]))
    # delete contacts
    delete_line_ranges(filename, line_ranges)
    return
```